# The Network Connection was lost from Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I got this error many times in my project and it very irritates me because I have full internet connectivity though I get this error repeatedly.

[image]

What is the solution...?

I am using

> Swift - 3.3
>
> Alamofire - 4.7.3

API Calling Code:

```
class  func post(_ URL: String, withParams params: [String : AnyObject], onView parentView: UIViewController, hnadler completion: @escaping ([AnyHashable: Any]!) -> Void) {
        var URLString  = String()
        URLString = APIConstants.kServerURL + URL
        var headers = [String: String]()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        
        Alamofire.request(URLString,method: .post, parameters: params , headers : headers)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/vnd.api+json"])
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( _):
                    var completionVarible = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
                    completionVarible = response.result.value as! [AnyHashable: Any]! as [NSObject : AnyObject]
                    completion(completionVarible)
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.handleFailureResponse(Error: error as NSError?, parentView: parentView)
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add your code to check

Comment: var URLString  = String()
        URLString = APIConstants.kServerURL + URL
        var headers = [String: String]()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Alamofire.request(URLString,method: .post, parameters: params , headers : headers)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/vnd.api+json"])
            .responseJSON { response in
                
                }

Comment: I called api as per normally we implement

Comment: Edit your question with this code

Comment: @ParthPatel show us what happens in completion of Alamofire call, I don’t believe that Alamofire shows errors as alerts...

Comment: Please check the code I have edited my question with code.

Comment: @ParthPatel and what happens in completion of `post`?

Comment: @RobertDresler it is return response data from api.

Comment: @RobertDresler When this error occurs. It executes only failure case.

Comment: Try in `failure` case print `error`, what do you get? I believe that you're setting *The network connection was lost* every time that some error occurs, then you're not able to find an error...

Comment: @RobertDresler I please check the code I am calling one method in failure and this method display only alert which is in error!.localizedDescription.

Answer (score 1):

If the alert appears immediately you may try to change the cache policy to 
 .reloadIgnoringCacheData

Comment: Where I have to change policy?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why this error occurs but I have also faced this error, so I have put one solution. This error has some unique error code. So check that error code and ignore alert over there or you can again try this API call if this error code you get.

Answer (score 0):

I find one solution to this issue if you using Alamofire.

First import Alamofire in your common class otherwise you can create a separate class for check internet connection.

> import Alamofire

```
class Connectivity {
    class func isConnectedToInternet() ->Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}
```

Call below method before you API call

```
if !Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
            ServiceHandler.ShowAlert(message: "Check your internet connectivity.", title: "Error", parentView: self) //This is my comman method for display alert.
            return
        }
```

Comment: I applied same logic for this issue, but this one will not help. you'll get same error.

Comment: Yes, Now I am getting network error before API call.